# Thymeleaf select and CriteriaBuilder

Tags: select, thymeleaf, criteria-api

It's a simple thing I want to do that somehow raises a complex issue.. I'm going insane over this...

I want to compare my Pages field using criteriabuilder; get all that are less than, so use 'le' for numbers ('lessThanOrEqualTo' doesn't work here ).

How can you send an Integer from a Thymeleaf select so that if it is not selected it won't be added to your search criteriaBuilder ?

In the select you're forced by thymeleaf to have a String "undefined" option as a first option. If I use Integer as the field type it won't bind this "undefined" option to the posted model where I would later filter it out from the criteriabuilder. The numbers are OK here though. I need it to work if not selected or undefined.

If I go the other way and choose a String field for Pages then it will not be parsed for ...
      le(Expression x, Expression y)

in the CriteriaBuilder. I cannot turn

```
 b.get("pages")
```

into

```
Expression<? extends Number> myInteger
```

I've tried everyway....

```
                        <select th:field="*{pages}"  ng-model="bookData.pages">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">  select an option  </option>
                        <option th:each="selectItem: ${refData.pages}"

                              th:value="${selectItem.value}" 
                              th:text="${selectItem.label}">Pages</option>
                        </select>


    List<Predicate> predList = new LinkedList<Predicate>();

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Book> c =cb.createQuery(Book.class);
    Root<Book> b = c.from(Book.class);



    if( (!pages.equals("")) && (!pages.equals("undefined")) ){
      predList.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(b.get("pages"), pages));

    }
```

How could you send an Integer from a Thymeleaf select to be compared in the query so that if not selected doesn't get added to the query?

Ahhhhhhh!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by Checking my Angularjs from the form

```
   $scope.processSearchForm = function() {

    var aData = $scope.bookData.author;
    var gData = $scope.bookData.genre;
    var pData = $scope.bookData.pages;

    if(typeof pData === 'undefined'){
        pData='0';
    }
```

and setting it to '0' if it didn't exist and therefore undefined/unselected.

I then went with Integer for the field, obviously the right approach.
It binds to the model and 0 is filtered out of the Query with the CriteriaBuilder.

Johnny O.